# Can you have a draw in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I was looking at a few questions about PUBG on this site, and from questions I've seen, matches cannot end in a tie.

Now I am wondering, is it the same for Fortnite? Can two people both get Victory Royales? Is it different for other modes? How about Final Fight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there are no draws, there is always one winner

It is also impossible for the last two people to die "at the same time" because of latency, the server will know who died first, or at least it will know who's "I died" packet reaches the server first

If you want to do some reading, here is a form post: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/forums/battle-royale/royale-with-cheese/113641-is-draw-somehow-possible

Comment: So it depends who gets the I Died message first? So it relies on internet speed? If i have a better network speed than my opponent and we draw, would i theclinally win?

Comment: @GamerM there are a few other bells and whistles under the hood, but essentially yes, if you both happen to visually die at the same time

Comment: Note that there is no "I died" packet, as that would imply that the client decides death; which is an obvious backdoor to hacking. The client only sends actions ("I walk", "I shoot", "I aim upwards", ...), the **server** uses everyone's input to figure out the game state, and then sends a message to the client ("you died"). This means that (without added logic), it is possible for two deaths to occur in a single frame calculation. However, Fortnite's server can implement extra decision logic, e.g. **arbitrarily** deciding that the first client to respond is given the win.

Comment: But there is no reason to assume that this is the decision logic that Fortnite uses (unless the devs have confirmed this). They could do the opposite (last sent packet), or decide a winner via overkill damage, or by alphabetical name, player level, or even simply a random dice roll. They can use any and all data that they choose to use in order to decide who wins - neither player will be aware that it was a "tie" anyway. Or they could allow a tie, though I can't find any evidence of existing ties. The implementation details are not known unless the devs actually speak up.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one exception that I've encountered and that is the current 5 teams of 20 also known as the Final Fight mode. In this mode the winner isn't the team that has survived while others are dead, but the game ends after some time in the third and quite small circle. When the game has ended the team with the most players left is the winning one (downed players count too). There are multiple times that I've been on the winning team when the clock has run out and I've gotten 'victory royale' while our and an enemy team had as many players left in the game. Therefore I assume that the rules allow draws in this particular mode.

The [Express](https://www.express.co.uk/entertainment/gaming/976442/Fortnite-Final-Fight-mode-limited-time-mode-Fortnite-v4-4-latest) seems to confirm my assumption saying:

> Once the timer expires, the team with the most players wins—and, in the event of a tie, the two teams (or more) tied in first place share the spoils.

**In all other modes there is no draw ending possible as they end in all other players in other teams dead.**

Answer (score -1):

You can get a draw if a game takes more than 20 mins in China everyone will win